# Uploading files in php and storing in an existing folder

Tags: php

I have a html form with 5 file upload inputs

```
<form action="../scripts/php/insert_imagery.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="upload" id="upload">

            <input type="file" name="upload[0]" id="1"> Upload image 1 </input>

            <input type="file" name="upload[1]" id="2"> Upload image 2 </input>

            <input type="file" name="upload[2]" id="3"> Upload image 3 </input> 

            <input type="file" name="upload[3]" id="4"> Upload image 4 </input> 

            <input type="file" name="upload[4]" id="5"> Upload image 5 </input>
</form>
```

They are sent to insert_imagery.php

insert_imagery.php creates a file directory path for the images to be put into

```
mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/profiles/".$username_entry."/user_images", 0777, true);
```

This works until I add my file upload script. When i add this, the file crashes.

Here is my code for upload...

```
$user_id = $rows['id'];
$business_name = $rows['business_name'];
$username_entry = $username_check;
$hashPass = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
    function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "")
    {
        global $link;

        if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
            $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
        }

        $theValue = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $theValue);

        switch ($theType) {
            case "text":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
                break;
            case "long":
            case "int":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
                break;
            case "double":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
                break;
            case "date":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
                break;
            case "defined":
                $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
                break;
        }
        return $theValue;
    }
}



mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/profiles/".$username_entry."/user_images", 0777, true);

$user_image_dir = "profiles";
$user_images = "user_images";

if (isset($_FILES['upload']) === true) {
    $files = $_FILES['upload']; 

    for($x = 0; $x < count($files['name']); $x++) { 
        $name = $files['name'][$x]; 
        $tmp_name = $files['tmp_name'][$x]; 

        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$user_image_dir/{$username_entry}/{$user_images}/{$name}"); 

        //echo '<pre>', print_r($files['name'][0], true), '</pre>'; 

        $image_upload1 = ($files['name'][0]); 
        $image_upload2 = ($files['name'][1]); 
        $image_upload3 = ($files['name'][2]); 
        $image_upload4 = ($files['name'][3]); 
        $image_upload5 = ($files['name'][4]); 

    }

    $insert_upload1 = "$user_image_dir/$username_entry/$image_upload1"; 
    $insert_upload2 = "$user_image_dir/$username_entry/$image_upload2"; 
    $insert_upload3 = "$user_image_dir/$username_entry/$image_upload3"; 
    $insert_upload4 = "$user_image_dir/$username_entry/$image_upload4"; 
    $insert_upload5 = "$user_image_dir/$username_entry/$image_upload5";
```

Any thoughts or advice on why this is not working...Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any output logs?

Comment: Errors? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Can you provide the output of `print_r( $files);`

Comment: print_r($files) no displaying anything. Its like theres a syntax error when i put the code in. I have edited my original post with the entire code minus includes and mysql INSERT

Comment: <form action="../scripts/php/insert_imagery.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="upload" id="upload">

Comment: I was missing a "}" at the end.

Now im getting this error message.

Warning: move_uploaded_file(profiles/Jack1234/user_images/1.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/welcometowarwick/scripts/php/test_upload.php on line 22

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpHhcr1N' to 'profiles/Jack1234/user_images/1.jpg' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/welcometowarwick/scripts/php/test_upload.php on line 22